# How do I inject a LocationManager in roboguice 2.0?

Tags: java, android, roboguice

The [Simple Example](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample) on the roboguice wiki shows that you can use `Inject` to inject a `LocationManager` instance into an Activity.  However, it appears that the API has changed since this example was written.  I cannot find `Inject` in any of the packages.  Is there a way to inject a `LocationManager` into my activity with the latest roboguice 2.0 API?

Here is the example code for reference:

```
class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
    @InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
    @InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
    @InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
    @InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
    @Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [2.0 Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/InstallationNonMaven) states that you must add the `Guice 3.0-no_aop` JAR file to your application.  That is where the `Inject` annotation is defined.